# Overriding Bean issue in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application where I have to override beans like jobLauncher. But when I tried to run the command clean install I am getting the bean override issue. It is working fine on my local machine but I am getting the issue over Jenkins, I don't know why it is not happening on my local machine.

I looked into the spring code they are extending the configuration class and overriding the bean. I tried to extend the SimpleBatchConfiguration class but I faced some issue and I don't think it's a good idea.

```
JobLaunher Bean in Application:

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

JobLauncher in Spring Batch:

    @Override
    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {
        return createLazyProxy(jobLauncher, JobLauncher.class);
    }

Error Logs:


APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'jobLauncher', defined in com.orange.alc.dabek.dataload.config.BatchConfiguration, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

2019-05-20 20:26:45.056 ERROR 12892 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@29f8134] to prepare test instance [com.orange.alc.dabek.dataload.job.PhoneJobTest@611a2d82]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at
```

I want to override the spring batch beans. I found that it's not a good approach to use spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true because It also hides some benefit. I also don't find the same property in my application.yml. Please let me know about the better solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to customize Spring Batch infrastructure beans (job repository, job launcher, transaction manager, etc), you need to provide a custom `BatchConfigurer` (See the [JavaConfig](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig) section of the reference documentation).

You can make your batch configuration class extend `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer` from Spring Boot or `org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer` from Spring Batch and override the `createJobLauncher` method.

Comment: I tried the same but in my code bean creation takes the parameter which is not the case in spring batch configuration. As you can see in the above code creation of job launcher bean taking jobRepository as a parameter. So I have to autowired JobRepository. is it right to do ?

Comment: you can remove that parameter and use `jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());`

Comment: I extend the SimpleBatchConfiguration and override the required beans but I still get the overriding issue.

Comment: I want to know  that by default JobRegistry is of MapJobRegistry Type

Comment: My answer says you need to extend one of the two `BatchConfigurer`s and **not** `SimpleBatchConfiguration`. In regards to `JobRegistry`, yes the default one is of type `MapJobRegistry`.

Comment: I have this problem, do you have any code sample that worked. tried to extend BasicBatchConfigurer but that have some dependencies to beans that is not getting autowired. do you have any working solution on this with code example ?

Comment: The hint to the reference documentation is perfekt.